# "To that which", could someone clarify this grammatically? And so the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/were-fed-never-ending-brexit-140539157.html)the 4th paragraph says,

> But with Britain heading for a Dec. 12 election that could return a very different parliament **to that which** ***rejected*** Johnson's plans, the future remains uncertain.

I don't understand the grammar of the bold part and accordingly the meaning of the whole sentence (especially the bold italic "rejected" comes right after it).

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb phrase is "different to",

> A cat is different to a dog.

But in this actual example, we are comparing two parliaments

> The new parliament will be very different to the old parliament.

In that example I used an adjective "old" to describe the parliament, but I could use a relative clause:

> The new parliament will be very different to the parliament which is currently sitting.

However this repeats the word "parliament". I can avoid this repetition with a pronoun. The pronoun used is the demonstative pronoun "that":

> The new parliament will be very different to that which is currently sitting.
>
> The new parliament will be very different to that which rejected Boris Johnsons plans.